# Error while creating TEMP table

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have this query

```
CREATE TABLE tempdb..TEMP_DET( DB_ID NUMERIC(5,0)  NOT NULL,
   DB_D VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
   LAN VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT ''N'' NOT NULL)
```

and I got this error:

> Server user id 13 is not a valid user in database 'model'

Does anyone know the reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like permissions for your user have been messed up.  Double check to make sure you are a member of a group that has permissions in model (public would be the most likely).  Also, double check to make sure public is a valid group in model.